# C++ Language If-statement flow

Tags: c++, if-statement

I want to know the flow of following `if` condition. It always print "Print 2". Why (12 && 14) is lesser than 10 ?

```
void main()
{
    int num=10;
    if(num < (12 && 14))
        cout<<"Print 1";
    else
        cout<<"Print 2";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `12 &&  14` is `true`. `12 & 14` would be `12`.

Comment: Did you mean `num < 12 && num < 14`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `std::cout` or a debugger:

```
int main()
{
    int num=10;
    std::cout << "(12 && 14) is " << (12 && 14) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "num < (12 && 14) is " << (num < (12 && 14)) << std::endl;
    if(num < (12 && 14))
        std::cout<<"Print 1";
    else
        std::cout<<"Print 2";
}
```

Displays:

```
(12 && 14) is 1
num < (12 && 14) is 0
Print 2
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/8zth)

`(12 && 14)` is evaluated as `(true && true)` because:

- `&&` is a `bool` operator
- `false` is 0 and `true` is anything else, so `12` and `14` are equivalent to `true`

So, `(12 && 14)` is finally evaluated to `true` being `1` (standard).Now  `(num < (12 && 14))` is then evaluated to `10 < 1` which is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` operator is not defined between `int`s, but is defined between `bool`s. So what happens here is that `12` and `14` are implicitly treated as `bool`s (i.e., `true`s, as any non-zero `int`). The result of `&&` between two `true`s is again a `true`. This `bool` value is then compared to the `int` literal `10`, so it's promoted to the `int` value of `1`. Since `10` is not less than `1`, the result of the `if` condition is `false`, and the `else` branch is executed, printing `Print 2`.

Answer (score 1):

`12 && 14` is will result `true`,

`true` means `1` in c

So here `n` is not less than `1` in your program. 
Therefore, the output of your program is `Print 2`